# Keep screen running after starting it with an alias and running some commands

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I have a bash alias to move into a project folder, start screen, and pull new changes from git.

it looks like this:

```
alias start_manager2='cd ~/programming/manager2/ && screen -t "main" bash -c "cd main && ./tools/fetch.sh"'
```

this 'works' - in that all of the commands are run, and I can see that screen is starting with a window entitled 'main', but as soon as the fetch script is done running, screen terminates.  What am I doing wrong here?

**solution**

```
alias start_manager2='cd ~/programming/manager2/ && screen -t "main" bash -c "cd main && ./tools/fetch.sh; bash -l"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `; read -p "Finished. Press Return.` before `"`.

Comment: that prints finished, but pressing return still terminates screen

Comment: If you want a bash add `; bash -l` before `"`.